# Tab out of {} from if statement vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs

I installed the tab out extension in vscode. It works fine for most things, expect when I use a if statement and have a block of code.

```
If (a=0) {
  printed("test");
}
```

After the `;` sign tab out won't work when the `}` sign is not at the same line.

Comment: better to ask at the repo of the extension

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.